# Python: .pop behaves different between same and different line

Tags: python, django

Can someone explain to me why these two code snippets behave differently?

Here I get the expected output `{datetime.date(2019, 6, 18): 12300}`

```
    events_sales_gross_last_7_days = events_sales_gross_last_7_days_incl_today.get(event.pk, {})
    events_sales_gross_last_7_days.pop(timezone.now().date(), 0)
    print(events_sales_gross_last_7_days)
```

The next snippet however only gives me back `'int' object has no attribute 'get'`.

```
events_sales_gross_last_7_days = events_sales_gross_last_7_days_incl_today.get(event.pk, {}).pop(timezone.now().date(), 0)
print(events_sales_gross_last_7_days)
```

Comment: Because in the first line you've reassigned `events_sales_gross_last_7_days` to the result of the `get` call, so now it's an int.

Comment: Okay I see, thank you @DanielRoseman!